# How to write an aligned equation with itemize centred bullets in latex?

Tags: math-mode, itemize, bullets

I need to write an inline equation with itemize in latex. I did the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
    The following two bullets:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $\begin{aligned}
        \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(t)\cdot\hat{g}_{i}(t)&=\sum_{i=1}^{L}f_i(t)\cdot\left[g_{i}(t)/f_i(t)\right]\mathds{1}_{\{j\}}(i)\\&=g_{j}(t).
        \end{aligned}$
        \item $f_i(t)\leqslant g_i(t)$ for all $i$.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The first bullet is not centred as the following figure shows:

[image]

Comment: Use  `\begin{aligned}[t]`. By default, it is vertically centred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want `\begin{aligned}[t]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}

The following two bullets:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
      \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(t)\cdot\hat{g}_{i}(t)
      &=\sum_{i=1}^{L}f_i(t)\cdot[g_{i}(t)/f_i(t)]\mathds{1}_{\{j\}}(i)\\
      &=g_{j}(t).
      \end{aligned}$
\item $f_i(t)\leqslant g_i(t)$ for all $i$.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I never thought it was that easy! Thank you.